# ASP.NET CORE WEB API app gives error on HTTPS on localhost

Tags: ssl, nginx, asp.net-core, centos

I just recently got my first VPS. It's running CentOS 8 and Nginx. I am using the default ASP.NET CORE REST API project, published it and deployed it to the server.

The setup is as follows:

Normal_Client_Browser <-->  Cloudflare_DNS/Proxy <--> Nginx_on_VPS <--> REST_API_on_Localhost_Kestrel

I've got Cloudflare serving its SSL. Then, Nginx is setting up as a reverse proxy. And, the dot.net core app is running on `https://localhost:5001` and `http://localhost:5000`.

Everything is working fine except when the app is accessed on the `https://localhost:5001` internally is giving SSL error:

> ERROR: The certificate of ‘localhost’ is not trusted.
>
> ERROR: The certificate of ‘localhost’ hasn't got a known issuer.

I have already made myself a self-signed SSL using OpenSSL and the certificates are working fine 100% for that matter. I've added the rootCA.pem to trusted list of CAs already. Nginx is using the SSL certificate and key I generated too for the reverse proxy. But, the certificate is not working either.

And, when I try to publicly access the website, I get the following error.

> This site can’t provide a secure connection.
>
> randomwebsite.com uses an unsupported protocol.
>   ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

However, if I disable https redirection on the app, the app runs just fine online. The problem is the localhost certificate not being trusted. For some reason, my certificate is not being used and Kestrel is generating its own certificate which surely will not match the one I setup in NGINX reverse proxy.

So, how do I set SSL certificate and key in ASP.NET CORE APP running on CentOS 8 using Nginx as a reverse proxy?

I am new to ASP.NET CORE so I'm having difficulty understanding the issue.

launchSettings.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:63514",
      "sslPort": 44370
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "weatherforecast",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "REST_API": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "weatherforecast",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace REST_API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
            });

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You must install ssl certificates `sudo apt-get install ca-certificates`

Comment: ca-certificates are already isntalled Marios

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @JorgeFernandezHerrero I didn't find any solution. Here's why! Linux does not allow for localhost SSL certificates....so it's best if I get a domain name for hosting and use my subdomain for that. Alternatively, instead of localhost, we can use sub domains and get SSL from letsencrypt and try with that.